# Using itertools.tee to duplicate a nested iterator (ie itertools.groupby)

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I'm reading a file (while doing some expensive logic) that I will need to iterate several times in different functions, so I really want to read and parse the file only once.

The parsing function parses the file and returns an `itertools.groupby` object.

```
def parse_file():
    ...
    return itertools.groupby(lines, key=keyfunc)
```

I thought about doing the following:

```
csv_file_content = read_csv_file()

file_content_1, file_content_2 = itertools.tee(csv_file_content, 2)

foo(file_content_1)
bar(file_content_2)
```

However, `itertools.tee` seems to only be able to "duplicate" the external iterator, while the internal (nested) iterator still refers to the original (hence it will be exhausted after iterating over the 1<sup>st</sup> iterator returned by `itertools.tee`).

Standalone MCVE:

```
from itertools import groupby, tee

li = [{'name': 'a', 'id': 1},
      {'name': 'a', 'id': 2},
      {'name': 'b', 'id': 3},
      {'name': 'b', 'id': 4},
      {'name': 'c', 'id': 5},
      {'name': 'c', 'id': 6}]

groupby_obj = groupby(li, key=lambda x:x['name'])
tee_obj1, tee_obj2 = tee(groupby_obj, 2)

print(id(tee_obj1))
for group, data in tee_obj1:
    print(group)
    print(id(data))
    for i in data:
        print(i)

print('----')

print(id(tee_obj2))
for group, data in tee_obj2:
    print(group)
    print(id(data))
    for i in data:
        print(i)
```

Outputs

```
2380054450440
a
2380053623136
{'name': 'a', 'id': 1}
{'name': 'a', 'id': 2}
b
2380030915976
{'name': 'b', 'id': 3}
{'name': 'b', 'id': 4}
c
2380054184344
{'name': 'c', 'id': 5}
{'name': 'c', 'id': 6}
----
2380064387336
a
2380053623136  # same ID as above
b
2380030915976  # same ID as above 
c
2380054184344  # same ID as above
```

How can we efficiently duplicate a nested iterator?

Comment: But if you tee the inner iterator, wouldn't you be reading the file twice?

Comment: you'd probably be better off by hardcoding everything into lists.

Comment: It seems `grouped_object` even in `tee` can not be used twice. This parallel doesn't work: `tee_obj1, tee_obj2 = groupby_obj, groupby_obj`. But I guess this gives the expected result: `tee_obj1, tee_obj2 = copy.deepcopy(groupby_obj), groupby_obj`. I guess..

Comment: "how to recursively copy an iterator" cannot be properly answered (or there is no solution) as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132731/how-to-create-a-copy-of-python-iterator but in your case it seems that `deepcopy` solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `grouped_object` (`class 'itertools.groupby`') be consumed once, even in [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).
Also parallel assignement of the same `grouped_object` doesn't work:

```
tee_obj1, tee_obj2 = groupby_obj, groupby_obj
```

What's working is a deep [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) of the `grouped_object`:

```
tee_obj1, tee_obj2 = copy.deepcopy(groupby_obj), groupby_obj
```

Comment: "It seems like grouped_objectct (class 'itertools.groupby') be consumed once, even in itertools.tee" I don't think this is true, otherwise `a b c` would not have been outputted the second time. I'll accept this answer though I was hoping to use something more elegant than `deepcopy`. Thanks!

Comment: what is true is that the grouper objects returned as "values" of each groupby iteration cannot be tee'd.